# Why a normal distribution is sufficient?

Tags: statistics

Consider a random sample from a normal distribution that has an unknown mean and variance. We have
$$f(\mathbf{x}\mid\mu,\sigma)=\prod^n_{i=1}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left[\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}(x_i-\mu)^2\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sigma^n(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \exp\left[\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\sum^n_{i=1}(x_i-\mu)^2\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sigma^n(2\pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \exp\left[\frac{-1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2-2\mu\sum^n_{i=1}x_i+n\mu^2\right)\right]$$

Since it still depends on $\sigma$, why is it a sufficient statistic?
Or the two dimension definition is different than one dim?

At the beginning, I want to see if it is sufficient statistic using the Factorization Theorem, but it seems fail? Is there a factor can be expressed as the $h(x)$?

Comment: Sufficient statistic means no other statistic would give additional information. For Gaussian mean and variance is enough to describe the distribution and so these are sufficient static for Gaussian.

Comment: "Sufficient statistic means no other statistic would give additional information." Can you explain this using an example?

Comment: Exapmples are there in the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic Please let me know if there is any specific questions.

Comment: At the beginning, I want to see if it is sufficient statistic using the Factorization Theorem, but it seems fail? Is there a factor can be expressed as the h(x)?

Comment: How did you try to proof Factorization Theorem?

Comment: I haven't ever proved it, should I?

Comment: Sorry, I mean did you try to verify Factorization Theorem by using suitable function as in the examples given in the wikipedia link.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the theorem? h(x)=1 can say it is sufficient @example of Bernoulli. 
I believed that I misunderstand "sufficient", how do we check if a distribution is sufficient or not?

Comment: The factor $h(x)$ in this cases is $1$.

Comment: @user131605 : To say that the pair consisting of the sample mean and the sample variance is sufficient for the family of normal distributions means that the conditional distribution of the whole sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ given the sample mean and the sample variance does not depend on the population mean $\mu$ or the population variance $\sigma^2$. ${}\qquad{}$